# randomizing location of black pixels in an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, pixel

Lets say i generate an image this way:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im = cv2.imread('target.jpg')
zzo = np.zeros(im.shape)
shp = (int(im.shape[0]),int(0.5*im.shape[1]),int(im.shape[2]))
zz = np.zeros(shp)
oo = 255*np.ones(shp)
cct = np.concatenate((zz,oo),1)
cv2.imshow('image',cct)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result is an image that is half white and half black. How can i randomize the locations of the black and white pixels? I've tried using the numpy `permutation` and `shuffle` functions but this doesn't appear to do anything to the image. The variable `im` is a 3D-array and randomizing the positions of the pixels requires moving an object that has three values per pixel (R,G,B) so pixel one is `im[0,0,:]`, pixel two is `im[0,1,:]` and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might think you could use `numpy.random.shuffle`, but it shuffles the first dimension only.  For your image, that would shuffle the rows, not all the pixels.

You *can* use `numpy.random.shuffle`, if you reshape your array from shape (m, n, 3) to (m*n, 3).  You can create a "view" of your array that has this shape and pass it to `numpy.random.shuffle`.  That will also shuffle your array, because `numpy.random.shuffle` operates in-place.  So after you write `cct = np.concatenate((zz,oo),1)`, you can do

```
np.random.shuffle(cct.reshape(-1, 3))
```

This won't work in general, because the `reshape` method can return a copy, and it that case, the above line will shuffle *the copy* in-place but it won't change the original array.  In your case, you have just constructed `cct` using `np.concatenate`, so the array is C-contiguous, and `cct.reshape(-1, 3)` returns a view.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to reshape int one long line of pixels and shuffle those:

```
>>> im2d = im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2])
>>> shuffle = np.random.permutation(im2d.shape[0])
>>> im2d[...] = im2d[shuffle]
```

This shuffles the pixels of `im` quasi in-place (it actually creates a new array and copies it back into `im`).

Answer (score 0):

The trivial way to generate an image with half black and half white pixels is to create an image with random values from a uniform distribution (whatever method and range is cheap on your platform), then threshold that image at half the range. This will lead to each pixel having a 50% chance of being black or white.

If you really need exactly half the pixels being black or white, you would need to compute the median and threshold at that. In that case, shuffling the pixels might be cheaper (as in the other 3 answers).